# How do I calculate the effective interest rate given a duration in months?

Tags: statistics

Based on an example, if I am given \$ 3000 interest for every \$ 100,000 deposited with the bank for 2.5 months.

How do I calculate the effective interest rate?

Comment: So the 3000 interest is for one year or for 2.5 months?

Comment: for 2.5 months.

Comment: 3000 of 100000 is 0.03. To obtain the effective interest I would calculate $i_{\textrm{eff}}=1.03^{\frac{12}{2.5}}-1$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The inital deposit $d$ grows to $1.03\times d$ in 2 1/2 months, grows to $1.03^p \times d$ in $p\times 2.5$ months.
Solving $p\times 2.5=12$ gives $p=12/2.5$ and a final sum of $1.03^{12/2.5}d=1.1524d$ after a year. So the effective yield is 15.2 %.